# if && statement help needed Newbie

Tags: arduino

I am trying to do this but can't seem to get it to work. Can someone please help

```
if (tft.fillScreen == (BLACK) &&((p.x > 163 && p.x < 200)&& (p.y > 295 && p.y < 314)))
{
  tft.print("bingo")
}
```

I'm getting

> invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)

I keep changing them around but i cant seem to get it right

Just to add, `black` is defined at the top of the code

```
#define BLACK    0x0000
```

Comment: This, `tft.fillScreen == (BLACK)` I believe should be `tft.fillScreen == BLACK` - remove the surrounding `()` Or change it to `(tft.fillScreen == BLACK)`

Answer (score 0):

Each statement that you are evaluating should be set apart with parenthesis. It helps make your code more readable and easier to understand.

I.E.

```
if ((tft.fillScreen == (BLACK)) && ((p.x > 163) && (p.x < 200))&& ((p.y > 295) && (p.y < 314)))
```

This will check that "tft.fillScreen == (BLACK)" is true, that p.x is between 163 and 200 and that p.y is between 295 and 314. If any one of these three conditions is not true than the entire statement evaluates to false.

Comment: im still getting invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)

Comment: im still getting invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)

Comment: I forgot an ending parenthesis. I fixed it now.

Comment: Nope not at this end.. its doing my head in this just one line of code out of 2500 lines and this is the one giving me the headache.. invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)

Comment: sketch seems to be highlighting the first parenthesis

Comment: So when you try to compile you get "nvalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)" as an error?

Comment: i have solved why its not working i cant use tft.fillScreen == (BLACK in a if statement as when i check to see if i can return the value it won't return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but...

1. What is `tft`? Is it coming from a library? Which one?
2. What is `fillScreen`? I think that it is a function to fill the screen, not a variable saying what is the background color
3. You missed the `;` at the end of `tft.print("bingo")`

Now, if point 2 is right (so `fillScreen` is a function):

This explains the error, since you are calling a function as if it was a variable. What are you trying to get? The last color you set as background? If so, probably you will need to save it in a variable.

If point 2 is wrong, then tell us what `tft` is..

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions.

Comment: It was more a solution than a clarification question.. If I understood the question in the right way the reason is that `fillScreen` is a function (or better, a method) and I propose a solution (i.e. saving the old value in a variable)